# How can I do a server-side redirect from legacy Servlet to JSF 2.0?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2

I am currently doing a client-side redirect to get from a legacy servlet (old part of an application) to a JSF page (new part of an application). I would prefer to do a server-side redirect if possible, so that I may place items in the request that the JSF page can pick up. (there is a set of data that needs to be "handed off" between the legacy servlet and the JSF page and I prefer not to put these in a client-side redirect URL (as URL parameters) but instead do this on the server-side).

If there is a way to do a server-side redirect between a servlet (not the Faces servlet) and a JSF page, can you please show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) the usual way. All servlets intercept on forwarded requests as well. You just need to make sure that the forward path matches the `FacesServlet` mapping. Assuming that you've mapped it on `*.xhtml`, this should do:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/page.xhtml").forward(request, response);
```

The page can if necessary be placed in `/WEB-INF` folder if you want to prevent the endusers from being able to open it directly without invoking the servlet first.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.xhtml").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned-- these are in different WARs and have different context roots. Will that be an issue?

Comment: If the server isn't configured to share the contexts (as by default), then yes, that will be a blocker. Otherwise, you'd just get the other context by `ServletContext#getContext()` and grab the request dispatcher from it instead. E.g. `getServletContext().getContext("otherAppName").getRequestDispathcer("/WEB-INF/page.xhtml").forward(request, response);` It's unclear what server you're using, but in case of for example Tomcat, check its documentation using keyword "crosscontext".

Comment: Great thanks-- incidentally am using WebLogic 11g. Will give that a shot. Thanks