# Serving jsf page/resources from WEB-INF

Tags: filter, jsf-2.2, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0, ocpsoft-rewrite

I understand that one of the ways to serve jsf page/resource from any location is via  [RequestDispatcher#forward()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)

for example response to http://domain/contextpath/someotherlink.xhtml can be mapped

> /WEB-INF/serving.xhtml

resource location with `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/serving.xhtml").forward(request, response)`

but the location of the mapped page get displayed in the action component like `<h:form>`

i.e `<form method="post" action="/contextpath/WEB_INF/serving.xhtml" >`
even with [OCPsoft Rewrite URLRewriteFilter](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/).

@Alex Tsurika did a offer a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512234/jsf-files-inside-web-inf-directory-how-do-i-access-them/30076976#30076976) but JSF Expert @Balusc [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512234/jsf-files-inside-web-inf-directory-how-do-i-access-them/30076976#30076976#comment-48267322) on the security hole of this approach even though he proposed [same dispatch approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499192/how-can-i-do-a-server-side-redirect-from-legacy-servlet-to-jsf-2-0#10499365)

**Question:**

1. how can this security hole be mitigated, as raised by @Balusc (**UPDATE:** I guess none as @Balusc cleared it in the comment)
2. how can `<form method="post" action="/contextpath/someotherlink.xhtml" >` be displayed instead of `<form method="post" action="/contextpath/WEB_INF/serving.xhtml" >`

so as to solve the question ask by @Paul H

[Is it possible to submit a form that has been rendered from a JSF page location in WEB-INF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681640/is-it-possible-to-submit-a-form-that-has-been-rendered-from-a-jsf-page-location)

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Alex's answer was already edited to fix the security hole. See timestamps and edit history. 2. This duplicates Paul's question.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC. I update the question. But Paul's question haven't being answered even though it can shed light on the second part of my initial question(I really don't think it a duplicate but even though its similar)